# How does the number of photons hitting relate to the amplitude of a photon bundle/classical wave?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, electromagnetism

I understand how the energy of an individual photon is $hf$ and how the number of electrons emitted in the photo-electric effect is proportional to the number of photons hitting per unit area.

Hence, my question is that how does this **number of photons hitting/passing through** relate to the classical **amplitude of the electric/magnetic fields** of the emergent phenomenon of multiple photons that is the classical light wave/collection of waves.

Any brief overview without incorporating complex Quantum Electrodynamics would be sufficient as I’m seeking for the results of those equations and not necessarily the whole process.